# Triangle and circle geometry question

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image: Diagram]

I let $AE=x$ and $EC=y$, , then drew line $AD$ to get right $\triangle BAD$, but I don't know where to go from here. I was thinking maybe power of a point and similar triangles, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Have you tried using coordinates and setting up equations?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\measuredangle B=\alpha$.

Thus, since $$\tan\measuredangle C=\frac{OA}{AC},$$ we obtain
$$\frac{5}{10}=\cot2\alpha$$ or
$$\tan2\alpha=2$$ or
$$\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}=2$$ or
$$\tan^2\alpha+\tan\alpha-1=0,$$ which gives
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{10}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$$ or...